# What advice did the Buddha give to corrupt officials?

Tags: modern-world, sutras, evil

I'm wondering if there were any such occasions, and what suttas/sutras this is recorded in.

Also if the Buddha gave advice to otherwise evil people besides Angulimala or Devadatta, or possible connections to psychopathy or sociopathy.

Comment: Was King Pasenadi corrupt?  I think the only advice he heeded from the Buddha was to moderate his eating, and he lost a bunch of weight as a result :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Corrupted officials: [Dhanañjani Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.097.than.html)

> "What do you think, Dhanañjanin? There is the case where a certain
>   person, for the sake of his wife & children ... his slaves & workers
>   ... his friends & companions ... his kinsmen & relatives ... his
>   guests ... his departed ancestors ... the devatas ... the king, does
>   what is unrighteous, does what is discordant. Then, because of his
>   unrighteous, discordant behavior, hell-wardens drag him off to hell.
>   Would he gain anything by saying, 'I did what is unrighteous, what is
>   discordant, for the sake of the king. Don't [throw] me into hell,
>   hell-wardens!' Or would the king gain anything for him by saying, 'He
>   did what is unrighteous, what is discordant, for our sake. Don't
>   [throw] him into hell, hell-wardens!'?"

Other evil people(demon): [Alavaka Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn10/sn10.012.piya.html)